# Refer to 'Program Files' on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c#, special-folders, program-files

In C#, how do I refer the following locations rather than hard-coding them?

- Program Files (x86)
- Program Files

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use:

```
System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
```

to get the program files folder on the machine. This will return whatever is correct for the application that is running. So for 32-bit applications on a 64-bit machine, it will return "C:\Program Files (x86)" on a English version of Windows.

Comment: This will also cope with internationalised versions of windows